# how to revert mongodb document remove?

Tags: mongodb

I have several dbs with several collections each. Some of these dbs are very similar in structure, so I accidentally removed an document from a collection. I want to revert this delete, since some of the values need to stay the same. If it cannot be undone, is there at least a log that shows what values were deleted?

Comment: Just as a follow up for anyone with this issue. MongoDb does not have revert functionality, so the only way to fix this issue was to restore a backup on a DR server, grab the document that was removed and insert it back. This of course only worked because this was a staging server and had it been production, the data would've been set back to the date/time of the backup.

Comment: What sort of deployment do you have (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster)? Restoring from the last full backup is the worst case outcome (short of not having a backup at all!) but other options to mitigate accidental data deletion in future might include [configuring a delayed secondary](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-delayed-replica-set-member/) (for a non-standalone deployment) or using a continuous backup service like [MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://cloud.mongodb.com/) (note: paid service).

Comment: There is no log with the full contents of deleted documents, but with a replica set configuration you should be able to find the `_id` of recent deleted/updated documents in the [`oplog` (operations log)](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which might help when restoring from your DR backup.